# Use method 'NewGlobalRef' to reference a global reference

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, native

I am writing an android jni application, and want to use many global references. **Can I reference a global reference with 'NewGlobalRef'**?

I have tried the following and it works, but I don't know if this is allowed. I also don't know if 'NewGlobalRef' principle is whether the **global reference points to a global reference** or **two global references point to an object** (like shared_ptr)?

```cpp
#include <jni.h>

class A {
public:
    A(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) : env(env)
    {
        globalRef = env->NewGlobalRef(obj);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(obj);
    }
    A(const A & a) : env(a.env)
    {
        // a global reference points to a global reference ?
        // or two global references point to an object ?
        globalRef = env->NewGlobalRef(a.globalRef);
    }
    ~A()
    {
        env->DeleteGlobalRef(globalRef);
        globalRef = nullptr;
    }
private:
    JNIEnv * env;
    jobject globalRef;
};

// main entry
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM * jvm, void * reserved)
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    if (jvm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK)
        return JNI_ERR;
    A a1(env, env->NewStringUTF("somthing"));
    A a2(a1);
    a1.~A();
    // Can I continue to use 'a2' after 'a1' is destroyed ?
    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}
```

I expect I can continue to use 'a2' after 'a1' is destroyed.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _"two global references point to a local variable"_, but yes, since you've created two new references to the underlying object (the string) and only deleted one of them, you can still keep using the remaining reference.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30753744/4139593) answer's your question

Comment: @TruthSeeker that's help me a lot, thanks.

Comment: When you return from your JNICALL stack, both of your Local variables will be destroyed and in the destructor you will `DeleteGlobalRef` so you cannot use anything after you `return JNI_VERSION_1_4;`. I am wondering why you are using GlobalRef at all in this case.